# Django хранение массива массивов в SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite

Доброго времени суток.
Сервер на джанго для обработки запросов. Принимает от клиентов запросы на хранение данных ЭЭГ.
Данные это:

> - Массив массивов, в одной записи ЭЭГ может быть от 4 чисел (Например если передаются данные с ЭЭГ аппарата с 4мя электродами то
>     будет передаваться массив массивов по 4 элемента в каждом). В одной записи ЭЭГ постоянное колличество чисел.

Эти записи нужно хранить в базе данных. Используется SQLite. Сейчас храню данные просто в поле models.TextField(). 
Подскажите какие есть еще варианты, возможно более подходящие, для хранения таких данных?

Comment: для хранения таких данный я бы создала несколько моделей которые бы соответствовали данному описанию

Comment: SQLite используется  во время разработки a не для хранения данных.

Comment: @  Boris The Animal, -"SQLite используется во время разработки a не для хранения данных." Выбор базы данных для рабочего сервера - это отдельная тема. К тому же, насколько я смог найти информацию в сети, в MySQL тоже подобного типа данных нет.

Comment: @Boris The Animal. - " для хранения таких данный я бы создала несколько моделей которые бы соответствовали данному описанию". Не могли бы по подробнее описать поле какого типа должна иметь такая модель?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал поле FileField. 
Может это и не лучший вариан, зато, если понадобиться, можно соханять любые данные любого формата. Сейчас использовал файл с json'ом.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Propertytype(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)


class Property(models.Model):
    property = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    propertytype = models.ForeignKey(Propertytype)
    EEG = models.ForeignKey(EEG)

class EEG(CommonInfo):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
```

Если я правильно понялa задачу

Propertytype включит в себе записи 4ох элементов

(Элемент1 ,  ..,.., Элемент4)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответы. Я вышел из положения путем использования поля FileField. Ожидается файл в формате JSON. Вынимаю его из формы вручную парсю(проверяю все нужные условия) и сохраняю модель. Может это и велосипедный костыль, но по крайней мере я полностью контролирую прием и сохранение данных.